# Searching for Web Git Client

Tags: php, git, web, client

I'm searching for a Web Git Client written in PHP that I can install on my server to manage my repos. Something like phpMyAdmin for MySQL.
I found [www.gitphp.org](http://www.gitphp.org/) which has quite some options, but a very rudimental interface.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: If `php` is not a strict requirement, I use [gitlab](http://gitlab.org/). Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438163/whats-the-best-web-interface-for-git-repositories), which has a bunch of other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer simont. gitlab is quite nice!

Comment: I found another client in your link post, which looks nice too [gitlist.org](http://gitlist.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

If `PhP` isn't a strict requirement, I'd recommend [`gitlab`](http://gitlab.org/).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438163/whats-the-best-web-interface-for-git-repositories) covers a bunch of other `git` web clients.

Answer (score 1):

What have you researched?

have you read any of the git documentation?

[simple web-based visualizer](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-GitWeb)

Comment: Yes I have. I have mentioned GitWeb in my question.

Comment: Oh wait GitWeb is actually different. The interface looks quite the same as the one from GitPHP.